# Código não executa em C no VsCode

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio-code, ide, compiladores

Eu segui 2 tutoriais, instalei o VSCode  e o compilador Mingw, Coloquei todas extensões necessárias, O C/C++ compiler run, entre outros. E coloquei o caminho do Mingw na PATH das variáveis do ambiente. Às vezes o código compila, outras vezes não, mas quando ele compila, ele não executa. Aparece a mensagem que está no print da pergunta. Ele fala que não está achando o arquivo, mas ele está lá.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit:
Quando eu executo sem o ".\" aparece isso aqui. vocês sabem como resolver? E quando eu executo com o ".\" aparece realmente que não é suportado no meu Sistema operacional. é do Linux mesmo.

PS C:\Users\carminha\Desktop\linguagemC> teste.exe

teste.exe : O termo 'teste.exe' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente novamente. No linha:1 caractere:1 + teste.exe + ~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (teste.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Suggestion [3,General]: O comando teste.exe não foi encontrado, mas existe no local atual. Por padrão, o Windows PowerShell não carrega comandos do local atual. Se você confia nesse comando, digite: ".\teste.exe". Consulte "get-help about_Command_Precedence" para obter mais detalhes.

Comment: Não deveria de ser ./teste.exe em vez de ./"teste,exe" ?

Comment: Sim, é ./teste.exe      eu coloquei assim e não com vírgula, com vírgula dá erro

Answer (score 0):

O `./` funciona apenas nos sistemas operacionais linux. Ele indica que estamos rodando o programa na pasta atual. Porém, no windows, basta executar `teste.exe` estando na pasta  da aplicação.

Comment: Sim, eu usei mas deu o erro que coloquei no comentário abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra ver ali no seu explorer que não existe o arquivo `teste.exe`.
O único arquivo executável é o helloWorld.exe

Você pode executar ele, estando no diretório que estão seus arquivos, apenas fazendo:

```
helloWorld.exe
```

Comment: Sim, eu usei mas deu o erro que coloquei no comentário abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Ele não consegue encontrar, muito possivelmente por causa do `./` você precisa colocar nas configurações simplesmente seuarquivo.exe

Comment: Sim, eu usei mas deu o erro que coloquei no comentário abaixo.